# Enviar dato numerico a través de Ajax retorna error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy queriendo pasar un dato desde un archivo `js` a un `php` por medio de `ajax`.

> Lo unico que necesito haces es obtener el valor de la variable `idTurno` (del archivo js) en mi archivo php, para de esa manera llamar una funcion desde este mismo php.

Hice lo siguiente:

```
                    var idTurno = calEvent.event._def.publicId;
                    // el valor de idTurno es un string con un numero entero, por ejemplo
                    // idTurno = "2"
                    var turno = { 'idTurno': idTurno }


                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'ajax/turnos.ajax.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: turno,
                        success: function(respuesta) {
                            console.log("bien",respuesta)
                        },
                        error: function(respuesta) {
                            console.log("error",respuesta)
                        }
                    });
```

En el `php`tengo lo siguiente

```
require_once "../modelos/turnos.modelo.php";
class AjaxTurnos{


    public $turno;
    public function ajaxEliminarTurno(){
        $datos = ($this->idTurno);
        $tabla = "turnos";
              $respuesta = ModeloTurnos::mdlEliminarTurno($tabla,$datos);

        return $respuesta;
    }

}

/*==============================
ACTUALIZAR TURNOS
==============================*/
if(isset($_POST["idTurno"])){

    $turnos = new AjaxTurnos();
    $turnos -> data = $_POST["idTurno"];
    $turnos -> ajaxEliminarTurno();
}
```

> En consola estoy recibiendo la respuesta `error` de `ajax`, no pongo el código del modelo ya que aunque devuelva únicamente un `return` en la funcion `ajaxEliminarTurno` sigo recibiendo un error.
>
> Edit. Ya que me preguntaron si podia poner el error, lo raro es que devuelve un error con `responseText = ""` y un `statusText = "OK"`, le aplique la propiedad `fail` como se indica a continuación, recibiendo el alerta **Request JSON parse failed**

```
                        $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'ajax/turnos.ajax.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: turno,
                        success: function(respuesta) {
                            console.log("bien",respuesta)
                        },
                        error: function(respuesta) {
                            console.log("error",respuesta)
                        }
                        }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                          if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                          alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                          alert('Requested page not found [404]');

                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                          alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

                        } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

                          alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

                        } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

                          alert('Time out error.');

                        } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

                          alert('Ajax request aborted.');

                        } else {

                          alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

                        }

                      });
```

Comment: Que error te devuelve?, pon la definición del error porfavor.

Comment: Como en realidad no veia el error, porque me devuelve responseText = "" y statusTet = "OK", hice la prueba que indiqué al final de la pregunta.

Comment: Dice que es JSON parse failed el error, antes de intentar parsear la respuesta a un json, haz comprobado que el json - string, que te devuelve ajax es un json valido para poder ser parseado?, a vecez pasa que enrealidad el json que estamos enviando desde el servidor hacia JS no esta en un formato adecuado o valido.

Comment: ``console.log(turno)`` (pongo esa linea antes de hacer la llamada ajax) devuelve ``{idTurno: "3"}``

Comment: @Riven si le aplico un parseInt antes, para que 3 sea numerico y no string, se pasa correctamente al objeto pero recibo el mismo error

Comment: @Riven le hice un JSON.parse() al objeto antes del ajax y ahora no arroja el error, pero devuelve un warning y no entra al success ni al error: ``Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1``, voy a investigar a ver que quiere decir eso

Comment: Eso significa que el JSON contiene caracteres no validos o esta mal formado, hay que corregirlo.

Comment: No, me confundi, no devuelve nada porque el json.parse tira un error... estoy donde empece

Comment: Me gustaria ver la parte donde devuelves los datos (no todo, solo ver como los devuelves de parte de PHP).

Comment: En esto entran en juego 3 archivos, un javascript y dos archivos php. El primer php es el que subi a la pregunta, el segundo php es el modelo donde tengo la funcion que debe conectarse a la DB y eliminar el elemento de ID = a lo que haya recibido por ajax. Pero no estoy pudiendo capturar ese numero en mi php, en javascript ya logre obtenerlo.

Comment: Pero usas json_encode para devolver los datos de php a JS cierto?

Comment: Cuando realice la pregunta no lo estaba usando, pero probé ponerlo y no hubo cambios. Creo que tengo errores conceptuales desde el principio, ya que la tarea a realizar es sencilla :( Es obtener un numero entero, supongo que no es necesario mandar un ``json`` pero no se como se haria en el caso de un dato entero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/turnos.ajax.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: turno,
    success: function(respuesta) {
        console.log("bien",respuesta)
    },
    error: function(respuesta) {
        console.log("error",respuesta)
    }
});
```

Ese es tu código original, tienes como valor de respuesta que quieres por parte de ajax un json (`dataType: json`), pero del lado del servidor no estas retornando un json supongo, así que por eso falla.

En vez de poner `dataType: json` pon `dataType: text` o directamente no lo coloques:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/turnos.ajax.php',
    data: turno,
    success: function(respuesta) {
        console.log("bien",respuesta)
    },
    error: function(respuesta) {
        console.log("error",respuesta)
    }
});
```

Comment: Si quieres recibir varios datos, será mejor idea si usar dataType como json, pero entonces deberas asegurarte de retornar una respuesta del lado del servidor como un json correctamente formado.

Comment: Habia llegado a probar eso, el tema es que en consola recibo "respuesta" únicamente, no estoy recibiendo ningún valor desde el archivo php. Debo tener algun problema en esa parte también. Me quedo con tu ajax, y buscaré el problema en el archivo php. Muchas gracias

Comment: Prueba a quitar todos los echo que tengas en tu PHP y pon al final un echo con cualquier valor a ver si retorna ese valor que indicas de manera correcta entonces ajax esta tomando como respuesta algo que haya antes de lo que quieres retornar.

Comment: para 'retornar' algun dato de php hacia JS, tienes que usar alguna funcion que te permita escribir en pantalla algo, entonces supongo que ajax esta tomando un valor de algo que no quieres (estas imprimiendo en pantalla algo antes de imprimir en pantalla aquello que realmente deseas), y aquello que quieres que se retorne, recomiendo que no imprimas nada excepto lo que quieres que se retorne, esto vale tambien para por ejemplo var dump y print r de php por si depronto las usas en alguna parte...

Comment: Recien comente el resultado de mis pruebas pero lo estaba haciendo mal. Probe unicamente retornar ``echo "hola"`` y recibo ``<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\ajax\turnos3.ajax.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />``

Comment: si, lo agregue en el codigo, siempre los solicita php, me falto porque lo tipee aca

Comment: Tienes parse errors en tu codigo php, alguna llave que te falto cerrar / abrir, algun parentesis que no pusiste o un ; que se escapa o alguna otra cosa... php no te dara una respuesta si hay errores ejecutando el archivo php.